# npm run use wrong node version

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed:

```
$ node --version
v14.15.4
```

and

```
$ npm --version
7.24.2
```

I add to package.json command

```
"node_version": "node --version"
```

and when I run it, I get wrong node version.

```
$ npm run node_version

> ng-project-test@0.0.1 node_version
> node --version

v12.22.12
```

How could this happen and how to fix it?
Many thanks!

Comment: Do you run your `npm --version` and `npm run start` on the same terminal ? When you change version / upgrade, you need to restart the terminal one time so that it updates stuffs i guess. Try restarting either the terminal, or VS Code if you use the VS console to start your project.

Comment: Yes I restart it. Same problem I have when run gitlab CI/CD inside Docker container.

Comment: Are you using any framework or tools, like Electron, or something that may bundle node by itself ?

Comment: This is angular project. Super simple project

Answer (score 0):

Sory, my bad. It happen cause of dependency inside package.json

```
"node": "^12.18.3"
```